# Why is post in java-script is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My $.post request is not working. I have literally tried everything
Any help will be appreciated.

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function sendData() {

        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var roll = document.getElementById("roll").value;
        var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
        var subgrp = document.getElementById("subgrp").value;
        var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
        var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
        var address = document.getElementById("address").value;

        $.post("http://rental-back.herokuapp.com/api/signup",
            {
                "email": email, "username": username, "password": pass, "roll": roll, "year": year,
                "subgrp": subgrp, "fname": fname, "lname": lname, "phone": phone, "address": address
            },
            function (data, status) {
                //  console.log(data);
                if (data.msg == "success") {
                    alert("Account created successfully");
                }
                else {
                    alert("Account not created");
                }

            });
    }
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>SignUp | CPS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/form.css">
</head>
<!-- multistep form -->
<body>
    <form id="msform" onsubmit="sendData()" action="SignIn.html" method="post">
        <!-- progressbar -->
        <ul id="progressbar">
            <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
            <li>Social Profiles</li>
            <li>Personal Details</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- fieldsets -->
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="">
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="">
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="">
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">College ID</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your college details</h3>
            <input type="text" id="roll" name="roll" placeholder="Roll Number" required="">
            <input type="text" id="year" name="year" placeholder="Which Year" required="">
            <input type="text" id="subgrp" name="subgrp" placeholder="SubGroup ID (eg: COE-1)" required="">
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous">
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" required="">
            <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required="">
            <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" required="">
            <textarea name="address" id="address" placeholder="Address" required=""></textarea>
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/form.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/aos.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="js/scrollax.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

i have tried debugging it with console.log() but it shows that $.post() query is not working.

There are no errors in console and the function sendData() is being called.

Post request is working fine in console. It is also working outside send data function

Comment: What exactly is not working? Any errors in your developer tools' console? (Or anywhere for that matter.)

Comment: Any errors showing up in your browser console? Is the function `sendData` executed at all?

Comment: No errors in console @ivar

Comment: similar code is working in another page

Comment: Where do you call the function `sendData`? Will you please make sure you call it? and maybe post your html if you do and still facing the same problem

Comment: @empiric yes the function **sendData** is executed only the post part is not working

Comment: @litesh1998 [If I run just the `$.post...`](https://jsfiddle.net/ars4cx85/), it shows me the success alert. (I did have to change http to https due to mixed content errors.) Without more info, we can't help you.

Comment: @Ivar I have uploaded the whole code in edit.

Comment: @litesh1998 You call `sendData` on submit, but you never cancel the actual submission. Your script will attempt to make the AJAX call, but page will redirect/refresh before you receive the result. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted) on how you can prevent that.

Comment: @Ivar I will try to make it work

Comment: @Ivar It worked. Thanks a lot!!!